# how to implement timer the right way in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, timer, draw, point

i am struggling to find out how to get the point in this program to change every second or two with a timer. i have tried some combinations, but that have been unsuccessful.
i believe there is something in the ActionListener that I might have failed on.

```
ArrayList<Point> punkter = new ArrayList<Point>();

int i = 0;
int n = 0;
public Point[] point = null;
private Timer timer;
Random rg = new Random();


public timer(){
    this.setTitle("Draw");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1010, 710);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    point = new Point[100];

    this.setVisible(true);

    timer = new Timer(500,this);
    timer.start();
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < punkter.size(); i++) {
        Point a = punkter.get(i);
        Point b = punkter.get((i+1)%punkter.size());
        g.fillOval(a.x,  a.y, 5, 5);
        g.drawLine(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
    }   
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++){
        point[i] = new Point(rg.nextInt(1000), rg.nextInt(700));
        punkter.add(point[i]);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a nested container; also, note that "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call repaint() on the component when you wish to repaint, otherwise the paintComponent (or paint) method may not be called. Possibly not directly related but advice worth giving (and noted in a comment by trashgod): use a Component added to the JFrame (like a JPanel), and perform all the drawing within the paintComponent method of this component (if you do so, you should call repaint on this component).